# подавить вывод ошибки в bash

Tags: linux, bash

хочу получить соответствие опкода и ассемблерной команды с помощью rasm2. написал такой скрипт.

```
#!/bin/bash

byte=0

for (( byte = 0; byte < 256; byte++ ));
do      
        a=$(rasm2 -a x86 -d "$byte" 2>>/dev/null)
        printf "%s %x\n" "$a" "$byte"
done
```

но он выводит ошибки без чисел, и мне бы хотелось узнать, как вообще подавить ошибки?

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

for (( byte = 0; byte < 256; byte++ ));
do      
        hex=$(printf "%x" "$byte")
        a=$(rasm2 -a x86 -d $hex 2>>/dev/null)
        if [ "$a" = "invalid" ]
        then
                continue
        elif [ "$a" = "" ]
        then
                continue
        fi
        printf "%s :%x\n" "$a" "$byte"

done
```

Comment: `if [[ "$a" =~ "invalid" ]] || [[ -z "$a" ]]; then continue; fi` используя логическое или `||` получится чуть меньше строк или если версия bash позволяет `if [[ "${a:-invalid}" =~ "invalid" ]]; then...` тогда проверка на пустоту не нужна